# Kotlin ByteArray from mixed types

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to create, in Kotlin, a byte array with mixed types in it.

Specifically, I need to write something like:

```
0, 1, 0x02, 1, "me@emailaddr.com"
```

to a characteristic over BLE using Kotlin.

Clearly I'm new to Kotlin.  The convenient ways to do it in Swift don't seem to have similar functions in Kotlin.

I've tried:

```
data class BlePayload(val protoVer: Int, val transId: Int, val cmdType: Int, val valueType: Int, val value: String)

fun packagePayload(): BlePayload {
    val checkinInfo: BlePayload = BlePayload(0, 1, 0x02, 1, "me@emailaddr.com")

    return checkinInfo
}

...

private fun writeCharacteristic(characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
    val payload = BluetoothUtils.packagePayload()

    val strByteArray = payload.toString()
    val byteArray = strByteArray.toByteArray()

    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "Writing to characteristic ${characteristic.uuid}")
    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** strByteArray = $strByteArray")
    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** byteArray = $byteArray")
    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** Writing the Payload: $payload")

    characteristic.setValue(byteArray)
}
```

But that seems to be cumbersome and wrong.  However, I can't see another way around it.

It needs to be a byte array for the Peripheral.

I can't find a way to make a byte array without making it a string first.

I don't see a way to go directly to a byte array with mixed types.

I am sure I must be wrong - I just seem to be too new to understand what the Kotlin docs are telling me.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK pulling in a library to help with this task, I'd consider using Square's [Okio](https://github.com/square/okio) for this one. I've used it for this kind of bit-fiddling in the past. Your example would look something like this with Okio:

```
fun packagePayload(): ByteArray =
     Buffer()
            .writeInt(0)
            .writeInt(1)
            .writeInt(2)
            .writeInt(1)
            .writeString("me@addr.com", Charsets.US_ASCII)
            .readByteArray()
```

Okio also offers little-endian versions of the above methods (i.e. `writeIntLe()`).

Comment: How to convert this back to the original object?

Comment: You can use a buffer to read back in the ByteArray and read out the fields in the order they were added. Buff#readyFully will read the whole array into itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up abandoning the idea of a data object in favor of:

```
fun packagePayload(): ByteArray {
    var payloadArray: ByteArray = ByteArray(0)
    payloadArray = payloadArray.plus(0.toByte())
    payloadArray = payloadArray.plus(1.toByte())
    payloadArray = payloadArray.plus(2.toByte())
    payloadArray = payloadArray.plus(1.toByte())
    payloadArray = payloadArray.plus("me@addr.com".toByteArray(Charsets.US_ASCII))

    Log.i(TAG_BLEUTIL, "** output of array: " + payloadArray.contentToString())
   // [0, 1, 2, 1, 109, 101, 64, 97, 100, 100, 114, 46, 99, 111, 109]

    return payloadArray
}
```

That ended up being a lot more simple.

Here's the catch: if you want 4 byte integers, there is not Kotlin helper fun to make that easy for you.

So you need to do something like this to get the 4 byte Int:

```
fun Int.toBytes() : ByteArray {
    var retArray = ByteArray(0)
    for(i in 0..3) {
        retArray = retArray.plus((this shr (i * 8) and 0xFF).toByte())
    }

    return retArray//.reversedArray()
}
```

In which case you would use it like so:

```
payloadArray = payloadArray.plus(0.toBytes())
```

Notice the "//.reversedArray()" at the end of the function.  That's in case you need to switch between little endian and big endian.

Hope that helps someone in the future.

Let me know if you have a better solution.

Thanks